# iOS Storyboards - How to re-use a View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard

I have an application that takes you through multiple steps (5-6 steps) that at the end of it you will have a newly registered account. I am using a storyboard and a lot of these steps have very similar (or identical) layouts and objects and elements within them. Right now what I am doing is simply creating a new View Controller for each of these steps and then altering the data within them to pertain to the specific step. When I look at my storyboard, I feel like their has to be a way to optimize this so that I don't have so many identical view controllers beside one another.

[image: Storyboard Screenshot Depicting Issue]

As you can see there are 5 view controllers that are almost identical and I am looking for a way to condense these to a single view controller or perhaps 5 view controllers that access a single view which contains the variety of elements you see in the image. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can only have one controller and based on the step id you can change the data of the elements, I am not sure what your requirement was for which you needed to create 5 view controllers.

Comment: What does all these steps do? Why do you need them in 5 view controllers?

Answer (score 0):

If your all view controllers' look is same then no need to create multiple view controllers.

You can only create one view controller and change view or content of view as per requirement.

Hope it helps